# ST_Clip not including pixels intersecting the border of a shapefile

Tags: postgis, raster, clip

I'm trying to clip a raster with a shapefile in PostGIS but want the clipped raster to include pixels that overlap the border of the shapefile which `ST_Clip` doesn't seem to be including.

Here is a screenshot of the shapefile loaded in QGIS:

[image]

This query returns the raster clipped using the boundary of the geometry (I'm not sure why it doesn't include the top section).

```
SELECT ST_AsTIFF(ST_Union(ST_Clip(r.rast, ST_Boundary(foo.area), true))) AS the_tiff
FROM (SELECT p.geom AS area FROM areas p WHERE p.orgname = '${name}') as foo
INNER JOIN ${rastTable} r ON ST_Intersects(r.rast, foo.area);
```

[image]

This query returns the raster clipped using the geometry (without wrapping it in `ST_Boundary`, notice that the boundary pixels are not included)

```
SELECT ST_AsTIFF(ST_Union(ST_Clip(r.rast, foo.area, true))) AS the_tiff
FROM (SELECT p.geom AS area FROM areas p WHERE p.orgname = '${name}') as foo
INNER JOIN ${rastTable} r ON ST_Intersects(r.rast, foo.area);
```

[image]

My goal is to have the union of these two rasters (both the interior intersections and the border intersections as I want to run statistics on them). I don't understand why `ST_Clip` doesn't include pixels in the raster intersecting with the border of the shapefile, is it supposed to? Do I really need to be taking the union or how should I write this query?

Basically, I want the rule to be if any part of the shapefile touches a raster pixel, then include the pixel.

**Small update**

I can get closer to the desired outcome using `ST_buffer(foo.area, .01)` but this seems like the wrong way to go about it (and still doesn't fix the upper curved section):

[image]

Comment: Is there a nodata value defined in the raster that would cover the missing part?

Comment: @Pierre nope, I've checked the backing raster tiles and while the nodata value is -9999 for the raster, none of the pixels in or around the clipped area have that value.

Answer (score 1):

I also found that st_clip is only returning values for the pixels that are entirely covered by the geometry. Seems there should be a way to get st_clip to return full coverage of the polygon but I couldn't find it. To get all the values for intersecting pixels, I didn't use st_clip but st_dumpaspolygons and processed as a vector.

```
WITH a AS (
-- get rasters that intersect with geometry and dump little raster polygons 
SELECT p.geom AS area 
    , (st_dumpaspolygons(r.rast)).*
FROM ${rastTable} r 
JOIN areas p ON st_intersects(p.geom,r.rast)
) 
-- filter to intersecting polygons 
SELECT geom, val AS 
FROM a 
WHERE st_intersects(area, geom)
```